# When do you use getSelected method on the Standard set controller?

Tags: visualforce

I'm new to the standard set controller, and tyring to understand the `getSelected()` method. When do you use it? Can you provide some use cases, and maybe some sample code?

Comment: Please revisit the [help] and [ask]. The format here is to ask questions about specific issues you are having. As written, this question is too broad to be on topic. Please [edit] your post to indicate what research you have done and where specifically you are stuck.

Comment: Most of the time when you override a standard List View Page - it allows for the selected items from the standard list view to be passed into your override page and controller.

Comment: There are at least two other open questions re standard set controller and what it's actually good for. @Boris points out what I think is the main use case - list views. Using it elsewhere seems problematic. I would love to see more info on this as I think it's not well conveyed. Here are two related posts. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/146897/10062 and http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/113777/10062